# Making Table without using Texttable

Tags: python

I am writing Python code to show items in a store .... as I am still learning I want to know how to make a table which looks exactly like a table made by using Texttable ....

My code is

```
Goods = ['Book','Gold']
Itemid= [711001,711002]
Price= [200,50000]
Count= [100,2]
Category= ['Books','Jewelry']


titles = ['', 'Item Id', 'Price', 'Count','Category']
data = [titles] + list(zip(Goods, Itemid, Price, Count, Category))

for i, d in enumerate(data):
    line = '|'.join(str(x).ljust(12) for x in d)
    print(line)
    if i == 0:
        print('=' * len(line))
```

My Output:

```
            |Item Id     |Price       |Count       |Category    
================================================================
Book        |711001      |200         |100         |Books       
Gold        |711002      |50000       |2           |Jewelry
```

Output I want:

```
+------+---------+-------+-------+-----------+
|      | Item Id | Price | Count | Category  |
+======+=========+=======+=======+===========+
| Book | 711001  | 200   | 100   | Books     |
+------+---------+-------+-------+-----------+
| Gold | 711002  | 50000 | 2     | Jewelry   |
+------+---------+-------+-------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You code is building your output by hand, using `string.join()`. You *can* do it that way but it is very tedious. Use string formatting instead.

To help you along here is one line:

```
content_format = "| {Goods:4.4s} | {ItemId:<7d} | {Price:<5d} | {Count:<5d} | {Category:9s} |"
output_line = content_format.format(Goods="Book",ItemId=711001,Price=200,Count=100,Category="Books")
```

Texttable adjusts its cell widths to fit the data. If you want to do the same, then you will have to put computed field widths in `content_format` instead of using numeric literals the way I have done in the example above. Again, here is one example to get you going:

```
content_format = "| {Goods:4.4s} | {ItemId:<7d} | {Price:<5d} | {Count:<5d} | {Category:{CategoryWidth}s} |"
output_line = content_format.format(Goods="Book",ItemId=711001,Price=200,Count=100,Category="Books",CategoryWidth=9)
```

But if you already know how to do this using Texttable, why not use that? Your comment says it's not available in Python: not true, I just downloaded version 0.9.0 using pip.

Comment: Texttable is not a builtin module .... One have to install it first .... I want to get a code that do the same job ....

Comment: Can you how to install it .... I have downloaded the same version .... Can you tell what to do next ... Thanks ...!!!

Comment: `$ pip install texttable`
The `pip` program should be on your path but if not it is usually in the `Scripts` folder.

Comment: This is first time I am doing it .... Can you elaborate it simply (not using technical terms) and step by step .... Thanks & Regards

Comment: @AhsanRasheed. Bear in mind I don't even know what operating system you are using. You need to open a command prompt (shell console session). If you don't know how to do that then search for help here on StackOverflow. Navigate (use `cd`) to the folder where Python is installed. It will have a subfolder called `Scripts`. In that folder there should be a program called `pip`. Issue the command `pip install texttable`.